# How to plot a histogram in R?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

Can anybody help me to plot this histogram in R. I dont know how to add the column "Age at visit".
My data includes year and age.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your data or a sample of it and the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Some hints: if you're using `ggplot2` (probably a good idea/the easiest way to do this), you need to use `cut()` to create a categorical age variable `age_cat`, then `geom_bar()` with `x=year, fill=age_cat` should work. (If these are humans, do you really have 112-year-olds in your data?

Comment: Do you mean the following code
ggplot(data = my_data) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = year , fill = age _cat))
How can I  cut that age and then include in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

You can color the bars by using the `fill` argument of `geom_bar()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  age_at_visit = sample(67:112, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  year = sample(2008:2012, 100000, replace = TRUE)
)

df <-
  df |>
  mutate(age_group = cut(
    age_at_visit,
    breaks = c(67, 70, 80, 90, 112),
    labels = c("67-69", "70-79", "80-89", "90-112"),
    include.lowest = TRUE
  ))

df |>
  add_count(year) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(year, fill = age_group), color = 1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "Age at Visit") +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::comma) +
  labs(x = "Year of Visit",
       y = "Number of Visits") +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = n), linewidth = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. your code worked for my data :) Dear Till, I am new in R and coding, how can I learn it like you to be an expert in R and data science?